# `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` for a system of PDE

Tags: python, scipy, pde

I'm using `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` to solve a system of ODE and it works fine. Now I'm introducing the spatial dependency and I'm having some issues.

This is a simplification of my system (diffusion plus reactions):

[image]

The time derivative is what `fun` returns (`solve_ivp` `fun` parameter). For the spatial derivative, I use a finite-different formula (by hand). For each position you have this set of equations, so `fun` returns the time derivatives of each `yi` at each `x`.

The code works fine and the result has sense, but I'm struggling with stability. The system is stiff and I use the `Radau` method. The problem is related to `rtol, atol` and the space discretisation, `dx`. If `atol` (dominates over `rtol`) is too big, the system diverges, but if it is too small, it also diverges, I have to also reduce `dx` to make it work. I think that the problem comes from `solve_ivp`, which is looking for very small `dt` to accomplish with `atol` but since `dx` cannot be affected by `dt`, somehow it diverges.

Do you know any general stability relation between `dx` and `dt`? Or may I use a different approach?

Comment: It’s a diffusion equation: dt < dx^2 for an explicit method like yours. Otherwise, look up “Crank-Nicolson”